# Loop through Dates vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, date, datagridview

I want to create a `datagridview` every day. Here is my code so far. It's not displaying any errors but when I run the code it just load the form but the `dgv` does not appear. What can I do?

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim start As Date = Date.Now
        Dim apocap As Date = Date.Parse(#8/22/2050#)
        Dim loopdate As Date = start

        While start < apocap
            Dim dgv As New DataGridView
            With dgv
                .Size = New Size(250, 250)
                .ColumnCount = 2
                .RowCount = 12
                .Location = New Point(12, 9)
                .Visible = True

            End With

            start = start.Date.AddDays(1)
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add them to your form. Additionally, you'll want to change the `.Left` and/or `.Top` (`.Location`) properties so they don't all stack on top of each other:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim start As DateTime = DateTime.Today
    Dim apocap As New DateTime(2050, 8, 22)   
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    While start < apocap
        Dim dgv As New DataGridView
        With dgv
            .Size = New Size(250, 250)
            .ColumnCount = 2
            .RowCount = 12
            .Location = New Point(12, (9 + (250 * i)))
            .Visible = True
        End With

        Me.Controls.Add(dgv)
        i += 1
        start = start.AddDays(1)
    End While
End Sub
```

For fun, I like to write it like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim start As DateTime = DateTime.Today
    Dim apocap As New DateTime(2050, 8, 22)
    Dim count As Integer = CInt((apocap - start).TotalDays)

    Me.Controls.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(
       Function(i)
           Return New DataGridView With {
             .Size = New Size(250, 250),
            .ColumnCount = 21,
            .RowCount = 12,
            .Location = New Point(12, (9 + (250 * i))),
            .Visible = True
            }
            'start.AddDays(i) is there if you need it
       End Function
    ).ToArray())
End Sub
```